# Changing a Class

Tags: java, android, xml

so I'm new to Android Studio and currently am coding an Othello board game app for my phone and in my first game class I open with:

`public class gameClass extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private board b = new board();`

And this works fine and runs the game but then I wanted to run the same code on another activity with a few alterations, so I copy and pasted the entire code from the 1st class onto the second class and then made a few modifications (including me changing the class name where appropriate) but for some reason the modifications come up on both activities when I run the program.

My question is how can I change 1 class so that it doesn't affect the other without making one of them a private class since I bring in subs from other classes and send data from class to class.

Edit: As more information is needed apparently, I'll show all the parts of code where there is the issue.

`public class game2 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    private board b = new board();`
   ....
    ....

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.play:
                mysound.start();
                b.playgame();
                setboard();
                current.setImageResource(R.drawable.blackothello3);

                counterforWhites.setText("WHITE : " + b.count(Colour.White));
                counterforBlacks.setText("BLACK : " + b.count(Colour.Black));

                showPossibleMove(); // The main issue is that this subroutine works in the other activity where this is NOT called for.

                break;
```

The code in the other class for the other activity is almost the exact same, the only exception is that the 
`showPossibleMove()` command is not there yet when I run that activity it shows the runs this sub and it shows the possible moves in that screen when I dont want it to.

Comment: That is not enough to help you. Please consider adding [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear . If you are willing to get true answer please put your codes here to see what you have done .

Generally , if you extend one class from `AppCompatActivity` , you are creating an activity that must be declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`.However , for passing any data from one activity to another your first option is `Intent`.

If you asked me , I would create a new activity from wizard not copying and past.

Hope these suggestions would help you.